# Rasterise a shapefile with gdal into a new raster file with multiple bands

Tags: shapefile, gdal

I want to convert a shapefile (polygons) which contains also 3 attributes (CO,NOX,SOx) with float values.

I used the following command

```
gdal_rasterize -a CO -a NOx -a SOx -ot Float32 -ts 1000 1000 -l emissions_shp /home/emissions_shp.shp /home/emissions.tif
```

and the result is a raster file with one band only. It seems that it gets only the last attribute (Sox).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rasterize into 3 single band rasters then merge them:

```
gdal_rasterize -a CO -ot Float32 -ts 1000 1000 -l emissions_shp /home/emissions_shp.shp /home/co.tif 
gdal_rasterize -a NOx -ot Float32 -ts 1000 1000 -l emissions_shp /home/emissions_shp.shp /home/nox.tif 
gdal_rasterize -a SOx -ot Float32 -ts 1000 1000 -l emissions_shp /home/emissions_shp.shp /home/sox.tif 
gdalbuildvrt -separate emissions.vrt /home/co.tif /home/nox.tif /home/sox.tif
gdal_translate emissions.vrt  emissions.tif
```